# How to set up TPU on Google-colab for pytorch and pytorch-lightning?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning

I have followed the guide on the pyTorch-lightnings websight:
[guide link](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/notebooks/lightning_examples/mnist-tpu-training.html), trying to set up TPU with the following commands.

```
 ! pip install --quiet "pytorch-lightning>=1.4" "setuptools==59.5.0" "torch>=1.8" "torchmetrics>=0.7" "torchvision" "ipython[notebook]"

 ! pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.8-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I get the **error message**.

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: torch_xla-1.8-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like my python version on colab is Python 3.9.16. Don't know what to do about this

Answer (score 0):

From the [pytorch xla repo](https://github.com/pytorch/xla#available-docker-images-and-wheels), you can use the colab tpu wheel `https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/colab/torch-2.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl` which is compatible with python 3.9.